# Does the matrix to have n Distinct eigenvalue ?

Tags: linear-algebra

An square matrix  is  similar to a diagonal matrix if and only of  the matrix  has  $n$ linearly independent  eigen vectors .
Does the matrix to have  n Distinct eigenvalue  ?

My attempt : i thinks  yes ,because  for diagonalisable Distincts  eigenvalue  is  required..

is it correct ??

Comment: $\mathrm{I}_2=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ is diagonalisable, but with only one eigenvalue.

Comment: If a matrix has distinct eigenvalues, then yes it is diagonalizable. But not all diagonalizable matrices have distinct eigenvalues, as the above comment shows.

Comment: You can have a denationalization matrix with duplicated values (and multiple independent vectors associated with that eigenvalue)

Comment: Different eigenvalues are not necessary. However, the algebraic multiplicity of each eigenvalue has to be equal to its geometric multiplicity (dimension of corresponding eigenspace) for the matrix to be diagonalizable. Take as example the identity matrix. All eigenvalues are 1s, and the matrix is diagonalizable ( since diagonal).